# Convert integer to bits

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit

I have byte to binary string function,

```
std::string byte_to_binary(unsigned char byte)
{
    int x = 128;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << ((byte & 255) != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++, x/=2)
       oss << ((byte & x) != 0);

    return oss.str();
}
```

How can i write an int to bits in same way? I don't want extra 0's at the beginning of binary string so that is why i can't figure out how to create a variable length each time.
Also, i'm not using std::bitset.

Comment: Well, then the question is, why are you not using `std::bitset`?

Comment: Because I'm using bitwise-operators.

Comment: @parc: And `bitset` overloads them. Next reason?

Comment: @parc: You're using `ostringstream` and `string`, so you're clearly coding in C++. Use C++ classes for the stuff they're made for. Next reason? :P This may sound a bit harsh, but you'll be thankful later on.

Comment: I'll convert them to use char arrays later.

Comment: @parc65 : If you want a C answer, then you should say so explicitly in your question and tag the question with `c` rather than `c++`.

Comment: @parc: Why are you so reluctant to use `std::bitset`? It is even constructible from your `byte`!! (You may have to watch out for endianess though.)

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason i'm not using bitset because it messes up with endianess.

Comment: @parc: Don't suddenly look for excuses. Test it. Also, I think my previous comment on the endianess might have been a mistake. Again, **test it**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll just post this as an answer. It is shorter, safer and, what's most important, it is ***done***.

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <type_traits>

// SFINAE for safety. Sue me for putting it in a macro for brevity on the function
#define IS_INTEGRAL(T) typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0

template<class T>
std::string integral_to_binary_string(T byte, IS_INTEGRAL(T))
{
    std::bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT> bs(byte);
    return bs.to_string();
}

int main(){
    unsigned char byte = 0x03; // 0000 0011
    std::cout << integral_to_binary_string(byte);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

> 00000011

Changed function name, though I'm not happy with that one... anyone got a nice idea?

Comment: Thanks, btw did you get that output from big endian or little endian OS?

Comment: +1 if you generalize that into a function template using `sizeof(T)` as the template argument to `std::bitset<>` so that it works with other integral types.

Comment: @ildjarn: Done, and thanks to you I noticed a bug.. one byte is CHAR_BIT bit, not 4 bit. :)

Comment: @parc: Little-endian, like most OS on x86-64. Take a look at [Wikipedia for a listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_operating_systems_on_architectures)

Comment: Oh, and I also added some SFINAE for safety, within a macro for brevity. Sue me for it. :)

Comment: So then endianness doesn't affect the order at all, maybe i'll go with it.

Comment: @parc: Yeah, it seems `bitset` takes care of that.

Comment: That SFINAE is missing a `::type` before the asterisk.

Comment: Maybe DecToBits or something?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work (though I hacked it up quickly and haven't tested):

```
#include <string>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
std::string to_binary(T val)
{
  std::size_t sz = sizeof(val)*CHAR_BIT;
  std::string ret(sz, ' ');
  while( sz-- )
  {
    ret[sz] = '0'+(val&1);
    val >>= 1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Portable code should use `CHAR_BIT` instead of hardcoding `8` and hold the result in `std::size_t` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using std:bitset and convert any number into bit string of any size, for example 64

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 std::bitset<64> b(836); //convent number into bit array
 std::cout << "836 in binary is " <<  b << std::endl;

 //make it string
 string mystring = b.to_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >();
 std::cout << "binary as string " << mystring << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned your wish for C style in the comments, you might consider using [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) (or _itoa) **if you are not worried about ANSI-C standard**. Many compilers support it in stdlib.h. It also strips the leading 0's:

```
unsigned char yourGoldenNumber = 42;
char binCode[64];
itoa(yourGoldenNumber,binCode,2); // third parameter is the radix
puts(binCode); // 101010
```