# templating integer of unknown bitsize

Tags: c++, templates, integer

How would I convert a binary/hexadecimal string into an integer, given that I don't know how large the string will be?

I want to what `atoi`/`atol` do, but I don't know what to output because I don't know if the value will be 32 bits or 64 bits. Also, `atoi` doesn't do hexadecimal, so `101` will become `101` rather than `0x101==257`.

I assume I need to use `template<typename T>`, but how would I create the variable to output in the function? `T varname` could be anything, so what makes `varname` a number rather than a pointer pointing to some random place?

Comment: What type do you have in mind to hold an int larger than 64 bit?

Comment: no idea yet. i should probably remove that part for now

Comment: WTH random downvote. That annoys me so much that it bothers me when it's not my question. Question makes total sense to me.

Comment: IMO It's the user's responsibility to employ a sensible type. But if someone has a way to tell if the template type is a pointer or not, feel free to point that out.

Comment: @Xaade @Pete Wilson : Just out of curiosity (having just upvoted): If you disagree with the downvote, then why go through the trouble of commenting without upvoting?

Comment: strtoul() will convert binary, but doesn't have the std charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Templates are a *compile-time* thing.  You cannot choose a data-type at run-time.  If your input values won't exceed the range of a 64-bit type, then simply use a 64-bit type.

One way (but by no means the only way) to do the conversion is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
T hex_to_int(const std::string &str)
{
    T x;
    std::stringstream(str) >> std::hex >> x;
    return x;
}

std::string str = "DEADBEEF";  // hex string
uint64_t x = hex_to_int<uint64_t>(str);
std::cout << x << std::endl;  // "3735928559"
```

Comment: thats what im doing right now, but how would i do that for binary strings? std::bin doesnt exist

Comment: I think what he might mean is to make a template so he doesn't have to rewrite code for every type of numerical variable.

Comment: yeah. i dont want to overload the same function with all the different types of ints

Comment: @Xaade, @calc: See updated answer for a function template.  I have no easy answer for binary conversion right now.

Comment: How about [my answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038718/convert-integer-to-bits/6038889#6038889) if I got the current problem right?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to define a bigInt class and then parse your string into that class; somthing like this class : https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like untested this:

```
int  // or int64 or whatever you decide on
hexstr2bin ( char *s ) {  // *s must be upper case
int result = 0;     // same type as the type of the function
  while ( *char ) {
    result <<= 16;
    if ( *char ) <= '9' {
      result += *char & 0xF;
    }
    else {
      result = ( *char & 0xF ) + 9;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```