# C++ How can I assign an input value to a std::bitset argument?

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

I want to make a simple program that will take number of bits from the input and as an output show binary numbers, written on given bits *(example: I type 3: it shows 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111)*.
The only problem I get is in the second *for*-loop, when I try to assign variable in *bitset<**bits**>*, but it wants constant number.
If you could help me find the solution I would be really greatful.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int maximum_value = 0,x_temp=10;
    //cin >> x_temp;
    int const bits = x_temp;

    for (int i = 1; i <= bits; i++) {
        maximum_value += pow(2, bits - i);
    }
    for (int i = maximum_value; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << bitset<bits>(maximum_value - i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038718/convert-integer-to-bits)

Comment: The answer to that question depends on the number being known at compile time. Not suitable for what the OP needs.

Comment: Unless you are required to use `std::bitset`, you can use the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173261/int-to-binary-conversion-explanation.

Comment: I wanted to try doing it the easy way. I am able to do it other ways. I just wanted to know if there is a glitch I can use to make it work

Answer (score 1):

A numeric ("non-type", as C++ calls it) template parameter must be a compile-time constant, so you cannot use a user-supplied number. Use a large constant number (e.g. 64) instead. You need another integer that will limit your output:

```
int x_temp = 10;
cin >> x_temp;
int const bits = 64;
...
```

Here 64 is some sort of a maximal value you can use, because `bitset` has a constructor with an `unsigned long long` argument, which has 64 bits (at least; may be more).

However, if you use `int` for your intermediate calculations, your code supports a maximum of 14 bits reliably (without overflow). If you want to support more than 14 bits (e.g. 64), use a larger type, like `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.

---

A problem with holding more bits than needed is that the additional bits will be displayed. To cut them out, use `substr`:

```
cout << bitset<64>(...).to_string().substr(64 - x_temp);
```

Here `to_string` converts it to string with 64 characters, and `substr` cuts the last characters, whose number is `x_temp`.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I understand, but can you tell me how can I limit my output when it comes to leading 0s?

Comment: So you don't want to display leading zeros? You might want to ask a different question for that (unless you figure it out by yourself somehow).

Comment: I mean I do, but only for the limited value. I don't want to show the number on 64bits but on 10 for example

Comment: My question concerns your statement "You need another integer that will limit your output". I don't know how to implement it

Comment: OK! Didn't understand at first. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define const int bits=10; as a global constant :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;
const unsigned bits=10;
int main() {
    int maximum_value = 0,x_temp=10;

    for (int i = 1; i <= bits; i++) {
        maximum_value += pow(2, bits - i);
    }
    for (int i = maximum_value; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << bitset<bits>(maximum_value - i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not the problem I have. I want to have a possibility to type the number of bits on my keyboard.

Comment: The template argument must be defined before compilation.